# Node fileSync() returning incorrect size on Windows due to newline differences

Tags: node.js, fs

I want to find the size of a text file in bytes, however, the standard method of `fs.statSync("/path/to/file")` returns the incorrect size, seemingly due to newlines. For example, a 461 byte file with 5 Unix-style `\n` newlines shows 466 bytes, presumably because it's silently converting the newlines to `\r\n`s before counting. The same command on the same file gives the correct result on Linux (but not WSL2), and Windows File Explorer shows the correct byte count.

My node version is 17.0.1, and I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: `.stat()` does not scan the file content to calculate the size, that would be horribly inefficient. It looks up this information from the master file table. Your idea that the line breaks could be responsible is a red herring. Make a test file that only contains a single line break, and see for yourself.

Comment: @Tomalak Huh, you're right. Why does it differ from file explorer's value then? And how can that value be recalculated in the file table?

Comment: Use nnotepad++ and use View > Show symbol > Show all characters on your file. You may see some unexpected whitespace characters.  And don't waste your time trying to reconcile your file sizes with Windows File Explorer.

Comment: You're confusing the file size and the "size on disk" , which always is a multiple of the file system's cluster size. A file uses as many clusters as needed for its content, but if it does not fill up the last cluster completely, the remainder stays blank because it can't be assigned to a different file. Pay attention to which value you're comparing.

Comment: Turns out the issue was that I had two versions of the file: one with Windows-style line endings and one with Unix-style. I thought that a) they were both Unix-style, and b) I was checking the same one anyways, but those both turned out not to be the case. Thanks to the people who helped!